# ko is undefined when using KnockoutJS with TypeScript and RequireJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, typescript

I'm learning [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) and having some issues defining a [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) view model and have the bindings work.

Below is the view mode:

```
module MyApp {
    export class MyViewModel {
        public clicked: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;

        constructor() {
            this.clicked = ko.observable(false);
        }

        myClickEvent() {
            this.clicked(true);
        }
    }
}
```

(The constructor may not be required.)

And here is how I'm using requirejs to load the modules:

```
require.config({
baseUrl: "../../Scripts",
    paths: {
        knockout: "knockout-3.1.0",
        jquery: "jquery-2.1.1.min"
    }
});

require(['knockout', 'jquery', 'myviewmodel'], (ko, $, myViewModel) => {
    $(document).ready(() => {
        var vm = new MyApp.MyViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(vm, document.getElementById("profile-bar"));
    });
});
```

The problem is when the following line:

```
this.clicked = ko.observable(false);
```

When the click event fires (seems to be binding to the HTML elemement OK), the following error occurs in the browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined

In previous attempts I'd used

```
define('myviewmodel', ['ko'], (ko) => {
```

etc to ensure the requirement was satisfied but using that approach I cannot see how to use the module and export a class to be used as a [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) view model.

Do you have any advice on what I've done wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You have a typo:  `knoctout: "knockout-3.1.0",` should be `knockout: "knockout-3.1.0",`...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was ultimately caused by trying to use a class when I should have been returning a function as per the [knockoutjs](/questions/tagged/knockoutjs) documentation, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/amd-loading.html.

It's now working well. The following approach allows for multiple view models on a [spa](/questions/tagged/spa) while having a master application view model that provides general functionality to the whole scope.

I'd like to know if there's a better/preferred approach.

init.ts

```
 require.config({
    baseUrl: "../Scripts",
    paths: {
        jquery: "jquery-2.1.1.min",
        knockout: "knockout-3.1.0"
    }
});

require(["jquery", "knockout", "appViewModel"], ($, ko, appViewModel) => {
    $(document).ready(() => {
        ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
            init: () => {
                return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
            }
        };
        ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;

        ko.applyBindings(new appViewModel());
    });
});
```

appViewModel.ts

```
define(["knockout", "firstnameViewModel", "lastnameViewModel"], (ko, firstNameViewModel, lastnameViewModel) => {
    return () => {
        this.fnvm = new firstNameViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(this.fnvm, document.getElementById("fn"));

        this.lnvm = new lastnameViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(this.lnvm, document.getElementById("ln"));

        this.fullName = ko.computed((): string => {
            return this.fnvm.firstName() + " " + this.lnvm.lastName();
        }, this);

        this.clearNameFields = (): void => {
            this.lnvm.clear();
        };;
    };
});
```

firstnameViewModel.ts

```
define(["knockout"], (ko) => {
    return function () {
        this.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
        this.firstNameCaps = ko.computed((): string => {
            return this.firstName().toUpperCase();
        }, this);
    };
});
```

lastnameViewModel.ts

```
define(["knockout"], (ko) => {
    return function () {
        this.lastName = ko.observable("Muppet");

        this.clear = (): void => {
            this.lastName("");
        };
    };
});
```

htmlpage1.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="Scripts/init.js" src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
    <div id="fn">
        <p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
        <p>First name capitalized: <strong data-bind="text: firstNameCaps"></strong></p>
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
    <!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
    <div id="ln">
        <p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
    </div>
    <!--/ko-->
    <p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: fullName"></strong></p>
    <button data-bind="click:clearNameFields">Clear</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The skip binding technique was borrowed from http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html.